# connecting to x11vnc server with remmina (black window shown and disappearing after < 1second)

Tags: 16.04, ssh, xorg, vnc, remmina

I'm trying to connect to to x11vnc using remmina on Ubuntu. Each time I try to connect, a black window (remmina) is shown which disappears after about < 1 second. Connecting and seeing the remote display works perfect when using another client (tried with ssvnc v1.0.29 - selecting 'no encryption').

Any hints about the underlying problem and how to solve it? I would really like to use remmina instead of ssvnc.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

remmina: 1.1.2

x11vnc: 0.9.13

running x11vnc with the following command:

> /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -localhost -loop -noxdamage -o
>   /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared

x11vnc log from one of my connection attempts using remmina (tunneled via ssh - so it appears as "connection from localhost").

```
10/11/2018 15:23:03 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:03   other clients:
10/11/2018 15:23:03 Normal socket connection
10/11/2018 15:23:03 check_access: checking against full string "127.0.0.1"
10/11/2018 15:23:03 check_access: client 127.0.0.1 fullmatch matches host 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:03 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
10/11/2018 15:23:03   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
10/11/2018 15:23:03 incr accepted_client=7 for 127.0.0.1:45132  sock=12
10/11/2018 15:23:03 Client Protocol Version 3.8
10/11/2018 15:23:03 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
10/11/2018 15:23:03 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
10/11/2018 15:23:04   8 bpp, depth 8
10/11/2018 15:23:04   true colour: max r 7 g 7 b 3, shift r 0 g 3 b 6
10/11/2018 15:23:04 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type ultraZip
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Using compression level 9 for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Using image quality level 0 for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Using JPEG subsampling 1, Q15 for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling cursor position updates for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling KeyboardLedState protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling SupportedMessages protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling SupportedEncodings protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Enabling ServerIdentity protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Using tight encoding for client 127.0.0.1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 client_count: 0
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Client 127.0.0.1 gone
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Statistics             events    Transmit/ RawEquiv ( saved)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  FramebufferUpdate   :      1 |         0/        0 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  LastRect            :      1 |        12/       12 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  tight               :     38 |     55358/  3686856 ( 98.5%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  ServerIdentify      :      1 |        42/       42 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  SupportedEncoding   :      1 |        92/       92 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  SupportedMessage    :      1 |        76/       76 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  PointerPos          :      1 |        12/       12 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  TOTALS              :     44 |     55592/  3687090 ( 98.5%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04 Statistics             events    Received/ RawEquiv ( saved)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  FramebufferUpdate   :      1 |        10/       10 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  SetEncodings        :      1 |        88/       88 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  SetPixelFormat      :      1 |        20/       20 (  0.0%)
10/11/2018 15:23:04  TOTALS              :      3 |       118/      118 (  0.0%)
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced exactly the same phenomenon (a successful connection with a black window which closed down in less than a second). I solved it by changing the **Quality** setting of the connection to **Best (slowest)**. With this change I'm able to connect successfully to the remote machine.

[image]

The difference seems to be in the encoding used. After this change, where the log previously said "Using tight encoding" it now says "Using hextile encoding".

For comparison my server is running Ubuntu 16.04, x11vnc 0.9.13 and using the same command as in the question, run as root. On the client side I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and Remmina 1.2.0-rcgit-29.